# Create recursive query for tree like data set

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion, hierarchical-data

```
| Col1      | Col2  | Col3      | Col4  | Col5
--------------------------------------------------
| B1        | A1    | somedata  | data  | somedata
| B2        | A1    | somedata  | data  | somedata
| B3        | A1    | null      | data  | somedata
| C1        | B1    | null      | data  | somedata
| C2        | B1    | 1         | data  | somedata
| D1        | C1    | 1         | data  | somedata
| D2        | C1    | 4         | data  | somedata
| D3        | C1    | 4         | data  | somedata
| Z1        | K1    | A         | B     | C
| Z1        | K2    | A         | B     | C



                    A1
                /       \          \ 
              B1        B2          B3
            /   \
          C1    C2
    /   \   \
    D1   D2  D3
```

I have the following table structure. Col1 holds children of Col2. Other columns have other related data. The table holds data for a tree like structure. Is it possible to create a query that'll provide all the children for A1. In this case it'll be

`B1
B2
B3
C1
C2
D1
D2
D3`

I'm only familiar with simple joins and can't figure out how to query the data. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at the Oracle CONNECTY BY clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't be too complicated:

```
SQL> with test (col1, col2) as
  2    (select 'B1', 'A1' from dual union all
  3     select 'B2', 'A1' from dual union all
  4     select 'B3', 'A1' from dual union all
  5     select 'C1', 'B1' from dual union all
  6     select 'C2', 'B1' from dual union all
  7     select 'D1', 'C1' from dual union all
  8     select 'D2', 'C1' from dual union all
  9     select 'D3', 'C1' from dual union all
 10     select 'Z1', 'K1' from dual union all
 11     select 'Z1', 'K2' from dual
 12    )
 13  select col1
 14  from test
 15  start with col2 = 'A1'
 16  connect by prior col1 = col2
 17  order by col1;

CO
--
B1
B2
B3
C1
C2
D1
D2
D3

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```